# Grouping namespaces in NDepend graphs

Tags: c#, ndepend

I've got a project with a base namespaces for shared interfaces and enums etc. This is divided into Base.Parameters, Base.Models and Base.Results, plus a few types just in Base.

Now, when I draw the dependency graph, it looks excessively cluttered because the base-component can potentially get 4 edges from all of the other components.

Is there a way to group the namespaces so instead of the mentioned four, I'd just have a single Base.*? I'm guessing I can use the .ParentNamespace property in CQL somehow, but I can't figure out how.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NDepend understands the concept of namespace group, but this concept is not queryable for now. Hence, the simplest way to obtain a graph with namespaces group, is to first visualize the namespace groups on the Dependency Matrix (by expanding the assemblies) and then *export the Matrix's Code Elements to Graph*, as shown in the pic below:

[image: NDepend Export Matrix Code Elements to Graph]

Enhancing namespaces groups and assemblies groups is something we'd like to propose in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be able to produce something usable from that.